# Will upgrading Firefox to the latest version clear my Awesome Bar database?

Tags: firefox, upgrade, awesomebar

I'm considering upgrading from Firefox 3.6.3 to Firefox 9, but concerned that I'll need to rebuild my Awesome Bar database from scratch. Is this a legitimate concern? Or will my current database be migrated?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox stores that sort of information inside a separate profile folder, which keeps track of all your personal settings, bookmarks, and history. This also means that it's kept separate from the install, so installing a new version shouldn't affect it.

To be absolutely certain, you can first make a backup of your [places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) file inside your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite), and then restore it if the upgrade doesn't keep it.

Older versions of Firefox used two separate files for bookmarks and history: bookmarks.html and history.dat. Starting with Firefox 3, however, they switched to using the single places.sqlite file. If you were coming from an older version of Firefox. It would be hard-pressed to keep it, but since your Firefox is newer than Firefox 3, you shouldn't have any trouble upgrading.

Comment: Uninstalling the old Firefox won't touch the Firefox profile which contains bookmarks, cookies and such.

Comment: Ah, okay, I wasn't sure about that. I'll change it.

Comment: To delete your Firefox profile at un-installation, you have to select the `Remove my personal data` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be *extra* cautious, you could upgrade your Firefox **incrementally**. Mozilla maintains an archive of all public releases at: [`ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/`](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

So, in your case, to upgrade from **Firefox 3.6.3** to **9.0**:

1. Download and install [Firefox 4.0](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/4.0/)
2. Download and install [Firefox 5.0](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/5.0/)
3. Download and install [Firefox 6.0](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/6.0/)
4. Download and install [Firefox 7.0](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/7.0/)
5. Download and install [Firefox 8.0](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/8.0/)
6. Download and install [Firefox 9.0](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/9.0/)